How to force x label on Matplotlib
I want to add labels on the horizontal and vertical axes on Matplotlib, and I can't seem to. Here's a minimal reproducible example:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate x and y
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
y = 1 + x + 0.4 * np.random.random(len(x))

plt.figure(figsize = (5, 2.7))
plt.plot(x, y, 'b.')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.savefig("tmp.png", dpi=300)

and the result show the y label, but not x. (Due to sstatic.net problems, I can't include the image here, but you can find it here.
I searched online and couldn't find a solution. If I added subplots or axes, I could do ax.set_xlabel("x"), but I think it should work without axes.
I have Python 3.11.6.
How can I force adding a horizontal label to a plot?

Can repro. Works as expected adding bbox_inches="tight".

Works fine here...
graph link, with X label I'm using python 3.9, what version are you using?

I have python 3.11.6.

That fixes it, thanks! Please write an answer, or let next users find the original question pointed from the duplicate.
